# A graph with n vertices and m edges has atleast $ n - m $ components, what if n and m are equal or n is less than m?

Tags: graph-theory

I understand what the theorem is trying to say, also the intuitive understanding of the proof. But how would the theorem work for the case when we either have one of the cases:

1. Equal $n$ and $m$
2. $n$ is less than $m$

Obviously then in $case \ 1:$ we would have the result as $0$ and in $case \ 2:$ we would have results as negative value which doesn't make sense

So does it mean that this theorem works only when n > m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue. Any graph has at least $-3$ components, and in particular this holds for graphs with $7$ vertices and $10$ edges. It sounds a bit strange to say out loud, but it is still true.

Comment: Ah, so it's just the case that it's weird to "say" it but obviously it's still true! Thank You!

Comment: @PratikHadawale There is another (rather obvious) theorem that any non-empty graph has at least 1 component. So if one theorem says your graph has at least 1 component, and another theorem says it has at least $-3$ components, nothing has really gone wrong. It's just that one theorem gives a more useful ("stronger") result than the other for your particular graph. You can put them together and say "any non-empty graph has at least $\max(n-m, 1)$ components".

Comment: aha, the way you put it ~ really solved my doubt. Strong result vs weak result!